# How to get the equivalent of Apache's Alias "/foo" /path/to/foo working in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx in front of HHVM to serve up an API which has a landing page listing available versions at / and the actual installed API versions at /api/[version]/.

My nginx config so far is as follows:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name api.domain.com;

    # Character Set
    charset utf-8;

    # Logs
    access_log /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/logs/access_log.nginx;
    error_log /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/logs/error_log.nginx;

    # Directory Indices
    index index.php;

    # Document Root
    root /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/public;

    # Location
    location /assets {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /api/1.0 {
        root /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/api/1.0/public;
        rewrite ^/api/1.0(.*)$ /index.php$1;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    # Error Pages
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Block access to .htaccess
    location ~ \.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Requests to `http://api.domain.com/` serve up the landing page correctly, however requests to `http://api.domain.com/api/1.0/foo` are still sent through to the index.php at `/www/vhosts/api.domain.com/public/index.php` instead of the one at `/www/vhosts/api.domain.com/api/1.0/public/index.php`.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? The Apache configuration I am switching across from is below for reference:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin tech@domain.com
    ServerName api.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/public/
    <Directory /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/public/>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/logs/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/logs/access.log combined
    ServerSignature Off

    Alias /api/1.0 "/www/vhosts/api.domain.com/api/1.0/public/"
    <Directory /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/api/1.0/public/>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /api/latest "/www/vhosts/api.domain.com/api/1.0/public/"

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV testing
</VirtualHost>
```

On an unrelated note, can someone please tag this with `hhvm` for me? I need at least 300 reputation to create the tag, and apparently no-one's ever asked any hhvm-related questions on here yet. :/

**EDIT:**

As per krisFR's suggestion below, I've tried modifying the `location /api/1.0` block as follows:

```
    location /api/1.0 {
        alias /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/api/1.0/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

However, this loads the code from `/www/vhosts/api.domain.com/public/index.php` instead of the code I want it to load at `/www/vhosts/api.domain.com/api/1.0/public/index.php`. Any further ideas?

Comment: I think the main caveat has to do with the `location ~ \.(hh|php)$` block that always run `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name`...

Comment: Hmm… Shouldn't the `root /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/api/1.0/public;` in `location /api/1.0` override that, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426812/nginx-try-files-alias-directives

This is a long [standing bug in nginx](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). But you can work around by using the root directive again. Kind of a hack, but at least it works.

At same time I would add a slashes to the locations directives.

```
location /api/1.0/ {
    root /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/api/1.0/public/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

NGinx also has an [alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directive.

Give it a try :

```
location /api/1.0/ {
    alias /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/api/1.0/public/;
    ...
}
```

**Edit :**

You could try this :

```
location ^~ /api/1.0/ {
    alias /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/api/1.0/public/;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm… `location /api/1.0 { alias …etc…; try_files …etc…; }` loads up the code from `/www/vhosts/api.domain.com/public`. Any ideas?

Comment: @TwoWholeWorms I've edited my answer

Comment: Nope. :( Still loads the code from /. :/

Comment: tried using root not alias `root /www/vhosts/api.domain.com/api/1.0/public` in location block?

Comment: did it work ? <!-->

Comment: My bad, guys, this got lost in the aether. Yes, @AntonyGibbs's suggestion was the fix. If you want to post it as answer, I'll tick it.